# Self-Study - Implementation of Selection Sort

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

I am working through CLRS (Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition) on my own. I have worked through Exercise 2.2-2 which asks for implementation of the Selection Sort algorithm. I have implemented the entire algorithm in C#. Can someone verify that I have indeed implemented Selection Sort or have I implemented some other type of sort? The program runs and sorts the array as it should.

```
using System;

namespace selectionsort{
  public class MainClass{
        public static void Main(string[] args){
            int[] numbers = {55,20,74,46,71,63};

            Console.WriteLine("unsorted: " + String.Join(",", numbers));        
            selectionsort(numbers);
            Console.WriteLine("sorted: " + String.Join(",", numbers));
        }

        public static void selectionsort(int[] A){
           for(int i=0; i<A.Length; i++){
            int smallest = i;

            //find smallest
            for(int j=i; j<A.Length; j++){
               if(A[j] < A[smallest]){
                   smallest = j;
               }
            }

            //exchange A[i] with smallest
            int temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[smallest];
            A[smallest] = temp;
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is standard selection sort

Comment: Maybe better suited for [codereview.se].

Comment: The code appears at first glance to be a correct implementation but the style is not standard C# style.

Comment: Can you now make a generic version that takes an `IList<T> where T : IComparable<T>` ?

Comment: Though the implementation is correct, it could be better. For example: your code does nothing if the size of the array is zero, which is good. But it does a lot of unnecessary work if the size of the array is one.  Such an array is already sorted; you could bail out immediately.  Similarly, if the current item happens to be the smallest item, you swap it with itself, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: @EricLippert - Thank you for the great feedback! I am going through CLRS trying to implement the algorithms using minimal C#. I will implement the suggestions that you have given me.

Comment: @libik - Thanks!

Comment: @SuyashGupta, you can also take a look at [rosetta code](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Selection_sort#C.23) for implementation in any language.